# S3FS file transfer fails after 500MB

Tags: s3fs

I am trying to transfer a file of size 900MB into S3 directory which is mounted using S3FS on EC2 instance. I installed S3FS using default config without changing any parameters.

Once file size hits 530MB while transferring it gets failed and temporary file is removed from that folder.

Is there any limitation for file size to upload in s3fs directory? or any parameter which is blocking this transfer?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure your temp folder size is enough for the upload?

Comment: How can I check temp folder size? I mounted using default config only @SelimEmreToy

Comment: Can you run s3fs with `-f -d` and share any error messages?